# REST API URLs for Magento

Tags: php, rest, magento, magento2, magento2.2

This is a quick task. I need to create a user using rest api call in magento.

I have created consumer key, consumer secret, access token and token secret in magento backend.

i am struck on the api url

http://35.205.34.98/index.php/rest/V1/customers

I tried this url from magento documentation and i get

```
{
    "message": "Request does not match any route."
}
```

I am looking for the right url i could get the customers list and using post request i can create a user.

Note: Magento version 2.2.1 and I am looking for rest solution not SOAP solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to say what goes on and whether `index.php` is necessary in your path.
I would do a little bit of debugging, just search for the error string "Request does not match any route." in your magento install. 
Mine is installed via composer, so the path is `/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/Router.php`

There is a function called `match` there, it checks the incoming URL with the list of REST paths in the system.
You can just print `$routes` array and see how the expected routes look like.  You can also print your request `$request->getPathInfo()` to see how it looks like. Make sure that the route for Customers matches your incoming request path.